# Sending Blob raw data of my webcam from Vue-axios to a Laravel backend

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, blob, webcam

I have webcam stream in a Blog object and I need to send it to my backend.
I made it:

```
setInterval(function(){ 
                var blobs=new Blob(that.chunks);
                console.log(blobs);//this displays that blobs is full of nnnnn bytes
                let form=new FormData();
                form.append("blob",blobs);
                axios.post("/meet/upload",form).then(resp => {                    
                    console.log(resp.data);
                    that.chunks=[];
                }).catch( err => {
                    console.log("upload fallito: "+err);
                    that.chunks=[];
                });

            }, 1000);
```

this is my console log:

```
Blob { size: 1743814, type: "" }
```

Blob is not empty, but in laravel when I'd like to read this data I have empty data:

```
public function upload(Request $req){
        $data=$req->blob;
        syslog(LOG_NOTICE,$data);
        return response()->json(['len_received' => strlen($data)],200);
}
```

infact if I do a  "sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog"
I receive a blank result and in browser console  is the same.
What is my mistake?
Thank you.
Bye

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same issue as you. I am using python (flask), I just knew that the blob file is stored as request.files. So maybe in your case, it should be `$data=$req->files->blob`.